# Storyboard assistant editor for a ViewController opens <projectName>-Swift.h instead of <viewController>.swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uistoryboard

I have a programmatic swift project that I'm converting to Storyboards. A particular interaction is grinding my gears.

When I click on a view controller `MyViewController` in a storyboard, the assistant editor opens up `myProjectName-swift.h` instead `MyViewController.swift`

I know I can click on the nav bar of the assistant editor and select my VC from the `automatic` drop down list but this is just adding more actions every time I switch VCs in storyboard.

Answer (score 4):

When you set you class to match your view controller, **usually** the assistant editor will open the right file.

This is how to select the class:

- Select your view controller in storyboard
- Open the identity inspector
- Select the class from the list

  [image: identity inspector]

Comment: I have the custom class on the Storyboard VC set but my problem still happens

Comment: In a new project the automatic dropdown doesn't have a .h file listed in it but my old project has one, why is this?

Comment: okay it turns out that .h file is in DerivedData. I cleared my derived data and everything works as expected

Comment: Did not work for me. I have deleted the DerivedData folder and retried again. I  still get the .h file as default. How it can be solved? I'm using XCode 8.0

Comment: Did you recieved XCode message to create Obj-c header?

Answer (score 0):

That -Swift.h file was generated by swift 2.2 and lives in the derived data folder.

After clearing derived data the problem seems to have resolved itself